# I cant get my code to open my .txt file and read if it has names in it

Tags: python

In my code, it asks what is your name and if your name is in the file then say welcome back then their name if their name is not in it then ask if they want for Cora to remember it if yes then write their name into the file.

```
def AI():
    names = open("\\\\ph-fss1\\Students\\S39055\\Desktop\\names.txt","w")
    name = raw_input("Hello and welcome to the Creative, Orginal, Reactive, A.I, Cora. What is your name? ")
    file.read(names)
    if name in names:
        print "Welcome back " + name
    if name not in names:
      print "You are a new user would you like to me to remember your name?"
      name_yes = raw_input("Yes/No: ").lower()
      if name_yes == "yes":
          file.wright(name)
          file.close()
```

Comment: `names` is the filename, not the contents (that you just ditched)

Comment: also i see `file.wright(name)`, should be `file.write(name)`

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Did you just get an `AttributeError` from `file.wright()`?

Comment: What does `file.read(names)` get stored into??

Comment: you are not storing the results of `file.read(names)` . name is just a file handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a look at a few improvements. Since you use `raw_input()` i'll assume Python 2.x:

```
def AI():
    # you can use r'' to specify a raw string and avoid using '\\' to escape '\'
    fpath = r'\\ph-fss1\Students\S39055\Desktop\names.txt'

    # this is called a 'context manager'
    # when you are done with your operations, the file will close automatically
    # the 'r+' mode opens for reading and writing
    with open(fpath, 'r+') as f:

        # this is list comprehension and I assume each name is on a new line
        # a set is a container for unique values
        # assuming that you will not have multiple of the same names
        # if so, how do you plan to account for them?
        names = set([line for line in f])

        print "Hello and welcome to the Creative, Orginal, Reactive, A.I, Cora."
        name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
        if name in names:
            print "Welcome back " + name
        else:
            print "You are a new user, would you like to me to remember your name?"

            # this is fine, but what happens I just put in 'y' or 'n'?
            # look for methods to handle invalid input
            choice = raw_input("Yes/No: ").lower()
            if choice == "yes":

                # because we opened the file in 'r+', we seek(0) which puts us at the top
                # then when we writelines(list(names)) we overwrite the entire file
                # and store the original data with the new name as well
                file.seek(0)
                names.add(name)

                # writelines() just writes an iterable versus a string
                file.writelines(list(names))
```

There are some design choices you have to make here. But if you have any questions, ask away.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that you never actual read the contents of the file in order to check if the name existed. Try this:

```
name = raw_input("Hello and welcome to the Creative, Orginal, Reactive, A.I, Cora. What is your name? ")

if name in open("\\\\ph-fss1\\Students\\S39055\\Desktop\\names.txt").read():
     print "Welcome back " + name
else:
  print "You are a new user would you like to me to remember your name?"
  name_yes = raw_input("Yes/No: ").lower()
  if name_yes == "yes":
      with open("\\\\ph-fss1\\Students\\S39055\\Desktop\\names.txt", "a") as myfile:
          myfile.write(name)
```